# Ansible replace module doesnt work same

Tags: ansible

Using ansible replace module to comment the below lines "ftp and telnet" in the AIX /etc/inetd.conf file

```
"ftp     stream  tcp6    nowait  root    /usr/sbin/ftpd  ftpd -l -u 077 -t 180"
"telnet  stream  tcp6    nowait  root    /usr/sbin/telnetd       telnetd -a"

Ansible playbook:

---
- name: comment the line
  hosts: server1
  vars:
    - line1: "ftp     stream  tcp6    nowait  root    /usr/sbin/ftpd  ftpd -l -u 077 -t 180"
    - line2: "telnet  stream  tcp6    nowait  root    /usr/sbin/telnetd       telnetd -a"
  tasks:
    - name: Take the file backup
      shell:
        cmd: "cp /etc/inetd.conf /etc/inetd.conf_`date +%F` "

    - name: comment the line
      replace:
        path: /etc/test
        regexp: "{{ item }}"
        replace: "#{{ item }}"
        backup: yes
        owner: root
        group: system
        mode: 0777
      with_items:
        - "{{ line1 }}"
        - "{{ line2 }}"
```

The code works perfectly fine with the file content

```
$ cat /etc/test
ftp     stream  tcp6    nowait  root    /usr/sbin/ftpd  ftpd -l -u 077 -t 180
telnet  stream  tcp6    nowait  root    /usr/sbin/telnetd       telnetd -a
```

but if I try on /etc/inetd.conf it doesn't comment both the lines.

=unclear=>Wondering both the files with same lines content<=, but doesn't work on /etc/inetd.conf and works on the test file. Pls help.

Comment: Does it comment even one?

Comment: You are over-complicating it. It is a simple sed-task `s/^ftp/#ftp/ s/^telnet/#telnet/`

Comment: What are the ownership and permissions? What user is executing the step? And please clarify your last statement.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. All you care about is replacing the line if it begins with a certain value, yes? The rest of the line doesn't particularly matter (unless it does...)

If that's right, then try this:

```
- name: comment ftp and telnet
  replace:
     path: "/etc/test"
     regexp: "^(ftp|telnet) "
     replace: "#\1 "
     backup: yes
     owner: root
     group: system
     mode: 0777
```